# Подключение redux к react native expo

Tags: redux, react-native, react-router

Начал изучение react native expo, посмотрел урок по создание route + tabs, в подходе который посмотрел, я так и не смог определить корневой файл (точку входа), в которой я мог бы использовать , чтобы прокинуть store в на каждый screen. Чтобы долго и детально не расписывать архитектуру проекта и не путать вас, вот видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-shpLyYBLc&ab_channel=SimonGrimm

Там достаточно проматать пару минут, и увидете идею и подход к разбивке. Route, строятся на базе файловой структуры, а точку входа так и не определил. (Похожий подход есть в next JS,однако там можно создавать входной файл обвертку, тут я не нашел про это информацию)

Заранее большое спасибо !